# How to set on button clicked event for Randomly Custom ListView Adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

I am creating custom listview adapter, which made with 2 textview(tvA and tvB), a spinner(with fixed 3 values) and a button(okButton). **The list's data are dynamically  filling.** **When buttonOk is pressed both getting both textviews values and also spinner's current selected item and toast it.**

How can i do this? sorry for my english.

Comment: What's your tried, bro?

Comment: can you show your adapter class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getView() method where you populating your values add this listener.

```
okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position, tvA, tvB, spinner));
```

and create the the OnItemClickListener class like this

```
private class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position, TextView tvA, TextView tvB, Spinner spinner) {
        mPosition = position;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // handle everything here
    }
}
```

Comment: looking good, can u please tell me what is position param in okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position, tvA, tvB, spinner));

Answer (score 0):

if all views are siblings then use following code

```
  ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.okButton))
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
                            RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) parentRow.getParent() ;                               
                            TextView tvA = (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.tvA);
                            TextView tvB = (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.tvB);
                            Spinner sp = (spinner) rel.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                            //list view position-
                            ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow
                                    .getParent();
                            int position = listView
                                    .getPositionForView(parentRow);

                            Toast.makeText(context, tvA.getText().toString() + " " + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(context, tvB.getText().toString() + " " + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(context, spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
```